# FancyBox2 iFrame size issue in IE9

Tags: iframe, internet-explorer-9, fancybox

A similar question was asked 11 months ago but received no reply. I am using FancyBox v2 in an osCommerce website. The iFrame function has been tested in Firefox & works perfectly.

In IE9, the iFrame seems to revert to a default setting, placing a small frame in an oversized window, with scrollbars. This overrides the manual settings I have made for width, resizing, scrolling etc.

The docType is HTML 4.01 Transitional.

Answer (score 0):

The other option is (assuming you don't have other jQuery plugins relying on 1.5) use jQuery 1.4.4 - this seems to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I followed SEO Suffolk's suggestion and tried a different version of jQuery. I was using jQuery 1.91 and IE9 was the only one not working. The iframe was small and in the upper left corner and it didn't grow bigger and place in the center of the screen like the other browsers would do (and how I wanted it to be). I down converted to 1.4.4 then 1.5 then it eventually worked in jQuery 1.6 with IE10,9,8,7 chrome, FF, safari.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried messing around with compatability mode in IE to see if it helps? If it does then you could try forcing it with an extra header: